# Increase Chrome profiler sampling rate

Tags: google-chrome, profiler

From looking online, it appears as if the chrome profiler samples 1000 times a second.  This seems to be a reasonable default that balances information collection without high overhead.  However, i'm finding the default to be not aggressive enough for my current task.

I was wondering if there was a way to configure this default so i could try a few more values.  I'm absolutely willing to take the increased overhead while smapling this task.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you interested in finding out how to make a program faster, or are you only interested in getting precise measurements of whatever the profiler makes measurements of? The second objective is usually not very helpful for the first. Some people think their "bottleneck" may be a short-running function, so they think they need frequent samples to hit it - not so. See point 9 of [*this post*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1779343/23771).

Answer (score 1):

There's high resolution profiling option in DevTools settings. If enabled it will sample with 10kHz rate.

Answer (score 0):

Use option `--profiler-sampling-interval` (not `--cpu-profiler-sampling-interval`, which doesn’t work on my machine) in the d8 command:

```
./d8 --profiler-sampling-interval=1000000 xx.js --prof
```

The option means sampling interval in ms. Default value is 1000, which means sampling per us.